# Finding every possible linear combination that equals a constant in R with boundary conditions

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

Been trying to figure this out, but been having issues and suspect that there's any easy way to do this. So say I have some vector of constants for example:

```
[1] -2 -3  1
```

Now say I want to define -2*x -3*y + 1*z = -5 and find every different combination of x, y, and z where x, y, and z are integers and abs(x), abs(y), and abs(z) are all less than or equal to 5. So the output would look something like.

```
2, 0, -1
1, 1, 0
1, 0, -2
0, 0, -5
```

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is as small as in your example, you can use this:

```
combs <- as.matrix(expand.grid(-5:5,-5:5,-5:5))    
combs[combs %*% c(-2,-3,1) == -5,]
#      Var1 Var2 Var3
# [1,]    3   -2   -5
# [2,]    0    0   -5
# [3,]   -3    2   -5
# [4,]    5   -3   -4
# [5,]    2   -1   -4
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the CRAN Task View in the integer programming section.